# Calculate the derivative of $\left[{\sqrt{\left(1+\tan\left(x\right)\right)...\left(1+\tan\left(2^{2015}x\right)\right)}}\right]$ when $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$\cssId{diff-var-order-mathjax}{\tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}}\left[{\sqrt{\left(1+\tan\left(x\right)\right)\left(1+\tan\left(2x\right)\right)\left(1+\tan\left(4x\right)\right)...\left(1+\tan\left(2^{2015}x\right)\right)}}\right]=\:?$

I have tried writing  it with sin and cos, tried some formulas for ${\sin\left(2x\right)}$,  ${\cos\left(2x\right)}$ and ${\tan\left(2x\right)}$ but I have had no meaningful results. Maybe the derivative when $x=0$  can be found without calculating it? I'm guessing it can be calculated pretty easily but I'm missing the answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Let $f(x)$ be this function. Let $g(x)=\ln f(x).$ Then $g'(0) = f'(0)/f(0).$

Comment: i was thinking to do $g=\ln f^2$, but eh same thing anyway right?

Comment: @BCLC Yes that should work out the same.